# Dose iptables NAT overwrite user agent of HTTP headers?

Tags: iptables, http, nat

If i use iptables to NAT all HTTP traffic behind another network, does it overwrite user agent of HTTP headers? The rules are as follows:

```
/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
/usr/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -o tap0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
/usr/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i tap0 -p tcp --dport 80 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't.

Those rules works on TCP and IP level and does not process data in higher level (HTTP)

To learn more about how iptables-based NAT works, [see here](http://www.slashroot.in/linux-nat-network-address-translation-router-explained)